# BigQuery problem - I can't extract quantity and products added to cart for product lists (Google Analytics - UA)

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Good night,

I am trying to create a query on BigQuery which include the following dimensions: Date, ProductListName, ProductSKU, ProductListPosition and the following metrics:Product List Views, Product List Clicks, Quantity and Number units added to cart.
Nevertheless, Quantity and Units added to cart are not working as expected. Both always show the same result (0). I have already check with Google Analytics the correct results so I know the figure I would have got if the query was correct.

Below these lines, the query I did
Could anyone please help me with that?
Thanks in advance

```sql
SELECT
    PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d",date) AS Fecha,
    product.productListName AS Lista_Producto,
    product.productSKU AS SKU,
    product.productListPosition AS Posicion_En_Lista,
    SUM(IF(product.isImpression = true,1,0)) AS Vistas_Producto,
    SUM(IF(product.isClick = true,1,0)) AS Clics_Producto,
    SUM(IF(hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = "3",1,0)) AS AddToCart,
    SUM(IF(hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = "6",1,0)) AS Cantidad_Comprada
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`
  ,UNNEST(hits) hits
  ,UNNEST(hits.product) product
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20170730" AND "20170731"
    --AND product.productSKU = "GGOEYFKQ020699" AND product.productListName = "Category" AND product.productListPosition = 1
    AND product.productListName != "(not set)"
GROUP BY Fecha, SKU, Lista_Producto, Posicion_En_Lista
ORDER BY Fecha DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use below as add_to_cart:

```
CASE
WHEN LEAD(productListName) OVER (PARTITION BY sessionID, productSKU ORDER BY hitNumber) = "(not set)" THEN LEAD(product_add_to_cart) OVER (PARTITION BY sessionID, productSKU ORDER BY hitNumber)+product_add_to_cart
ELSE
product_add_to_cart
END
```